# Change color of the item being dropped jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ny1n9gm0/8/) I want to be able change the color of the item inside an accordion after it has been dropped. This is the script of the drag and drop function:

```
$(function() {
    var itm = [];
    $("#savebutton").click(function() {
        LISTOBJ.saveList();
    });
    $("#myAccordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
    $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $(".leader ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var zz = ui.draggable.text()
            var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
            if (xyz === false) {
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                    //.addClass("cart-item")
                    .addClass('dropClass')
                    .appendTo(this);

                //add to array
                itm.push(zz);
                //add style
                $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").addClass('bred');
                var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");

            } else {
                alert('Name is Already Exist');
            }

        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            count = count - 1;
            $(this)
                .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                .find(".myAccordion")
                .html("Out!");
            $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            $(ui.item).css("background", "red");
        }
    });
    $(".checker ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var zz = ui.draggable.text()
            var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
            if (xyz === false) {
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                    //.addClass("cart-item")
                    .addClass('dropClass')
                    .appendTo(this);

                //add to array
                itm.push(zz);
                //add style
                $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").addClass('bred');
                var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");

            } else {
                alert('Name is Already Exist');
            }

        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            count = count - 1;
            $(this)

            find(".dropClass")
            $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");

        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
    $("#myAccordion ul").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            var zz = ui.draggable.text()
            $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").removeClass('bred');

            var indexItm = itm.indexOf(zz);
            if (indexItm > -1) {
                itm.splice(indexItm, 1);
            }
        },
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover"
            //accept: '.cart-item'
    });
});
var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        $(".proc").each(function() {
            var listCSV = [];
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                listCSV.push($(this).text());
            });
            var values = listCSV.join(', ');
            $(".procChecker").append("<input type='hidden' name='prodstuff[]' value='+values+' />");
            $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
            console.debug(listCSV);
        });
    }
}
```

As I said, I want to change the color of the item being dropped inside an accordion. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

In your draggable function, add:

```
$("#myAccordion li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    drag: function(e, i) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('blue')) {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your css add:

```
.blue{ background-color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to change color of the source element which is dropped somewhere. To do so, you need to store that source element object when you start dragging it. You can change color when the object dragging is finished or dropped.

See reference fiddle,

```
<a href="Link">http://jsfiddle.net/Geupm/365/">Link</a>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: its helpful, thank you. But how to do so that color will change exactly when item is dropped. For example if user would like to drop 'local shirt' and start to drag it to drop zone, then he changes his mind on a half way and just leaves it out of the drop zone to item disappear. in that case color should not be changed. Is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: Yes it is possible, please find updated fiddle.

<a href="Fiddle">http://jsfiddle.net/Geupm/367/">Fiddle</a>

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

add a small line of css to override the default one like so :

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
background: red !important;
}
```

updated fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/ny1n9gm0/13/

Comment: i need to change color of item in `myAccordion` not on dropped item